# ReactiveUI Observable as Property Helper equivalent in Prism?

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

I use ReactiveUI and Prism in different apps and there are things that i would take from both.
Especially, the **Observable as Property Helper** feature from ReactiveUI.
https://reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/observable-as-property-helper/

Is there a way to make a Property observe another property in Prism? I know this can be done with commands, where they can observe properties, but it's not what I need.

One common use case is show/hide elements based on other properties, but i could think of many.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take some good from ReactiveUI, you can start with Rx! Perhaps there is already an implementation of OAPH somewhere, but you can write it yourself. I would start with something like this:

```
public sealed class ObservableAsPropertyHelper<T> : IDisposable
{
    private readonly IDisposable _cleanup;
    private readonly BehaviorSubject<T> _subject;

    public ObservableAsPropertyHelper(IObservable<T> source,
        Action onPropertyChanged,
        T initialValue = default,
        IScheduler scheduler = null)
    {
        var subscription = source.StartWith(initialValue)
            .SubscribeOn(scheduler ?? CurrentThreadScheduler.Instance)
            .Subscribe(_subject);

        var onChanged = _subject.Subscribe(_ => onPropertyChanged());

        _cleanup = new CompositeDisposable(subscription, onChanged, _subject);
    }

    public T Value => _subject.Value;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _cleanup.Dispose();
    }
}

public static class ObservableExt
{
    public static ObservableAsPropertyHelper<TValue> ToProperty<TObj, TValue>(this 
        IObservable<TValue> target,
        TObj source,
        Expression<Func<TObj, TValue>> expression,
        TValue initialValue = default,
        IScheduler scheduler = null)
        where TObj : BindableBase
    {
        if (!(expression?.Body is MemberExpression memberExpression))            
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(expression));
        
        string propertyName = memberExpression.Member.Name;

        return new ObservableAsPropertyHelper<TValue>(target, 
            target.RaisingPropertyChanged(propertyName), 
            initialValue, 
            scheduler);
    }
}
```

To make it work you need [Reactive Extensions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Reactive/)
Be cearful it's just a concept, i dont't test it yet.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain myself well enough. I already use RxUI but I have an app where I use Prism and I would like to find a wayto trigger an event when a property changes (like RxUI allows you to do)

Comment: RxUI is WPF framework built on top of Rx library. It maybe not good desision to mix several WPF frameworks like Prism and RxUI. But nobody forbids to use only Rx.

Comment: I am not trying to mix them. In this new app i am only using Prism, all i am asking is if Prism has that same useful feature that RxUI has

Comment: You can write that feature yourself, thats all i wanted to say.